# Subtracting lambda expression from Action

Tags: c#, lambda, action

I tend to use Actions to pop events up to parent objects. For example:

```
public class Child
{
    public Action<int> onNumberChangedDelegate;

    private int m_Number = 0;

    public void SetNumber(int number)
    {
        this.m_Number = number;

        if (this.onNumberChangedDelegate != null)
            this.onNumberChangedDelegate(this.m_Number);
    }
}
```

Sometimes I need the parent to relay this event to its own parent:

```
public class Parent
{
    public Action<Child, int> onChildNumberChangedDelegate;

    private Child[] m_Children = new Child[];

    public void SetChildren(Child[] children)
    {
        this.m_Children = children;

        foreach (Child child in this.m_Children)
            this._ConnectChildDelegate(child);
    }

    private void _ConnectChildDelegate(Child child)
    {
        child.onNumberChangedDelegate +=
            (int number) => this._ChildNumberChanged(child, number);
    }

    private void _ChildNumberChanged(Child child, int number)
    {
        if (this.onChildNumberChangedDelegate != null)
            this.onChildNumberChangedDelegate(child, number);
    }
}
```

So you can see I'm using a lambda expression to feed the child into the next Action.

The next step in my workflow is to setup a "disconnect" method. Essentially I need Parent to stop relaying the events of Children that are no longer assigned to it:

```
private void _DisconnectChildDelegate(Child oldChild)
{
    child.onNumberChangedDelegate -=
        (int number) => this._ChildNumberChanged(child, number);
}
```

Unfortunately this does not have the expected (at least, what I originally expected) behaviour, since it is creating a new lambda expression and trying to subtract that from the Action. This does not remove the original lambda.

My solution to this has been to create a dictionary:

```
Dictionary<Child, Action<Child, int>>
```

and to do this for every event that I need to relay. This way I can populate the dictionary when Children are added, and subtract the generated lambdas when children are removed.

So, my questions are:

1) Is my workflow awful? This is a style I've adopted from PyQT, so I imagine it probably doesn't belong in C#.

2) Is there a better way of getting an Action to pass the object that owns it? I'm hoping someone can tell me I'm using Actions wrong.

Thanks,

Ves

Comment: Perhaps you are looking for [events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/awbftdfh.aspx)?

Comment: I'm struggling to see the advantages of using events over Actions. I'm reading this article: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11541/The-Simplest-C-Events-Example-Imaginable

It looks like their solution is to pass "this" as a parameter.